# InvalidCastException was unhandled webBrowser1

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
     public delegate string GetStringHandler();

    public string GetDocumentText()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            return Invoke(new GetStringHandler(GetDocumentText)) as string;
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.webBrowser1.InvokeRequired)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                return webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the error at the second return under the else parenthesis.

How can I invoke webBrowser1?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
public delegate string GetStringHandler();

public string GetDocumentText()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        return Invoke(new GetStringHandler(GetDocumentText)) as string;
    }
    else
    {
        return webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get Specified Cast is invalid.

Comment: `OuterHtml` already returns a string - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.outerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Tim, I need to invoke webBrowser1, but I have no clue how to.

Comment: how do you create webBrowser1?

Comment: webBrowser1 is created through the .net control onto the form.